# How to include the canvas in an Inkscape PNG export?

Tags: inkscape, export, canvas

A designer has provided an SVG file for a logo centered on a square canvas.
However, when I tried to export the the file to a PNG, the following happened:

- only the logo text itself was included, the canvas was absent
- the background of the logo was transparent, although Inkscape showed a white (canvas) background.

**How can I export the logo with the entire canvas and ensure it is white?**

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to the answer below, I also found the background color window. It's far from clear what that means, but the trick is that on the `RGB` tab, you need to set the *opacity*, **A** (for *Alpha*) to be 100 which is quoted in [%] and not 1-255 like the other values. Or you can set the `RGBA` to `hhhhhhff`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Inkscape the canvas has no fill by default. The canvas is transparent despite being shown as white on-screen.  You can see this transparency in Inkscape if you go into *File > Document Properties* and set the *"Chequerboard background"* option. Exporting an SVG as PNG will therefore result in areas with no objects being rendered as completely transparent.

Here's one solution:

1. Draw a white filled rectangle that is big enough to cover all the artwork (or the entire canvas), and move it to the bottom of the object stack using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>End</kbd>, or do *Object > Lower to bottom*
2. Select the filled shape and the artwork, then in the Export PNG Image dialog <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, choose the *"Selection"* tab, and hit *Export*.